# ESP32: interrupt error (The following tasks did not reset the watchdog in time)

Tags: esp32

My system includes 2 ESP32 devices, communicating over ESPnow protocol. The slave device (connected to a Joystick)  is transmitting only when a changes occur, yet there can be several changes in a short time. The Master receives the transmission and executes upon. It starts running OK, but from time to time the master gets the following error and reset:

**6429) task_wdt: Task watchdog got triggered. The following tasks did not reset the watchdog in time:**

The master loop is empty, so to my understanding it runs endlessly (like NOP?) until an interrupt is received. However, the function registered with

```
esp_now_register_recv_cb(OnDataRecv);
```

is not very short. So perhaps this is the cause for the error.
I guess I could use a handling routing to collect the messages from the slave, but in this case it doesn't matter if a packet of data will be lost from time to time. I prefer losing old data rather than responding to it late.

Any ideas how to solve this problem? perhaps stop registration of the **OnDataRecv** when the master is working on the service routine? and re-register it when ready?

the relevant code:

struct_message myData;

// callback function that will be executed when data is received
void OnDataRecv(const uint8_t * mac, const uint8_t *incomingData, int len) {
memcpy(&myData, incomingData, sizeof(myData));
my_tank.tank_go_vector(myData.x_val,myData.y_val,myData.button_state,range);
} // of OnDataRecv()

The registration within setup:

```
esp_now_register_recv_cb(OnDataRecv);
```

The routine that executes:

```
void tank_go_vector(int _x, int _y,int _button,int _range) {

    Serial.print("  >> in tank_go_vector: x/y/button/range ");
    Serial.print(_x);
    Serial.print("..  ");
    Serial.print(_y);
    Serial.print("..  ");
    Serial.print(_button);
    Serial.print("..  ");
    Serial.print(_range);
    Serial.print("..  ");
    
    // go by vector recieved from joystick;
    
    
    int x_speed = abs(_x);
    int y_speed = abs(_y);

    x_speed = map(x_speed,0,_range,0,SERVO_RANGE); // 255 for 8 bits
    y_speed = map(y_speed,0,_range,0,SERVO_RANGE);

    Serial.print("   x_speed / y_speed: x/y ");
    Serial.print(x_speed);
    Serial.print("..");
    Serial.print(y_speed);

    if (_x==0 && _y==0) {
      Serial.println("  stop");
      left_motor.stop();
      right_motor.stop();
      return;
    }

    if (_x==0 && _y>0) {
      Serial.println("  forward");
      Tank_forward(y_speed);      
      return;
    }

    if (_x==0 && _y<0) {
      Serial.println("  backward");
      Tank_backward(y_speed);
      return;
    }

    if (_x>0 && _y==0) {
      Serial.println("  Right Pivot");
      Tank_right_pivot(x_speed);
      return;
    }

    if (_x<0 && _y==0) {
      Serial.println("  Left Pivot");
      Tank_left_pivot(x_speed);
      return;
    }

  // now deal with vector moves TBD

  } // of tank_go_vector
```

Comment: Or maybe just kick the dog during long looping operations. Without your code it's impossible for us to help you.

Comment: @Majenko I added the code.

Comment: I did some trials and found out that if the number of transmissions is reduced, the system is working well. Since it is OK to lose some packages, as long as the master is handling the latest package, How can I program the ESP32 master to stop receiving ESPnow messages while handling the current message? and enable it afterwards?